# Trying to use Dynamic Columns in JQGrid but end up with empty grid

Tags: jqgrid

I trying to figure out why my grid is loading but completely empty. I am just not sure what I am missing or doing incorrectly.

Here is an example of the JSON

```
{
"columns": [
    {
        "name": "ID",
        "index": "ID",
        "width": "5",
        "align": "center",
        "hidden": "true"
    },
    {
        "name": "WorkRequestID",
        "index": "WorkRequestID",
        "width": "55",
        "align": "center",
        "hidden": "false",
        "sorttype": "int"
    },
    {
        "name": "ProductName",
        "index": "ProductName",
        "width": "70",
        "align": "center",
        "hidden": "false"
    }],
"headers": [
        "ID",
        "WR#",
        "Product Name",
        "Project Name",
        "PL Assigned"]
}
```

Here is a portion of the grid code

```
    var columns;
    var headers;

    var columnInfo = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ColumnHandler.ashx",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            columns = data.columns;
            headers = data.headers;
        },
        fail: function () {

            alert("Failed to retrieve Columns");
        },
        async: false
    });

    jQuery("#gridlist").jqGrid({
        url: 'PSRHandler.ashx?task=get&display=' + display,
        mtype: 'GET',
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: {
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "ID"
        },
        colNames: headers,
        colModel: columns,
        pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
        rowNum: 8,
        scroll: 1,
        scrollrows: false,
        editurl: 'psrhandler.ashx?task=save',
        gridview: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', true],
```

Like I mentioned above, the grid does appear with no errors on the page but has no columns or data displayed. I would have posted an image but I don't have enough reputation points

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To have grid correctly filled you need to specify `colModel` and `jsonReader` which corresponds the **input data**. Could you include an example of input data in your answer? Some clear errors can be seen in the code which you posted: the properties of `colModel` items have to have correct type of data. For example the `hidden` property is **boolean**. So one should use `"hidden": true` instead of `"hidden": "true"`. In the same way `width` is number and not a string. By the way because you use `jsonReader: {id: "ID"}` you don't need to have hidden `'ID'` column in the grid.

Comment: Ok, so I resolved my issue. It ended up being some bad JSON. I used JSONLint, and was getting an error about invalid array length. It ended up being a missing brace in part of the code, and a missing comma. I also changed back to using non-string values for the boolean and int fields. I had changed to a string when I was trying to solve the issue. Should I be reading the input data outside of the grid with using this new dynamic method? Other than one less call to the database, does it provide any additional value? For the ID column, so you are saying one will automatically be created? Thanks